# How to implement urlencode in a HTML form that uses post?

Tags: php, decode, encode

Given this HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link" rows="3" action="add2.php" method="post"  placeholder="link here">
```

I want to encode that URL at first and then send it to `add2.php`.

`add2.php` is as follows:

```
    <?php

$url=$_GET["linki"];

       include("../db.php");
       $url=$_GET["linki"];
       $html = file_get_contents("$url");
       preg_match('/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*?)" \/>/', $html, $matches);
       preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $html, $title);

       $pdo -> exec("INSERT INTO `postss`(`link`) VALUES ('$w')");

    ?>
```

Server replies with "fordinended error" when I try to sumbit the URL.

Comment: That's most certainly not a valid text input up there. (text input itself does not have a parameter `action`. It's put inside a form with that parameter and a submit button)

Comment: why ? its bootstrap form

Comment: yeha your are true i have sumbot button with action ... but itsnot problem/...

Answer (score 0):

To keep this short: Your example does not show a valid HTML form and your question does not reflect what you're trying to accomplish in your code.

This might give you a starting point though.

The HTML form:

```
<form action="add2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" placeholder="Link here">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
</form>
```

add2.php for processing (there's partly copy/pasting from your Q inside since I can't / won't verify the functionality of your code itself):

```
<?php
include("../db.php");

if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $link = $_POST["link"];
    $html = file_get_contents($link);

    preg_match('/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*?)" \/>/', $html, $matches);
    preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $html, $title);
    $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO `postss`(`link`) VALUES ('$link')"); // Homework: SQL Injection, read up on it. This is still vulnerable.
}
```

Note that you're not using anything you did with the received contents inside your original question either... half of the code above is simply useless and the other half needs reading up on SQL Injection. Should get you started with form submission and handling though.

Comment: its saving title and image in mysql  $pdo -> exec("INSERT INTO `postss`(`link`) VALUES ('$w')");

Comment: maybe hosting dont allow to send link via post or get

Comment: Read the note... this has nothing to do with url encoding or the like. You're not using half the values you're creating in your question either (`$matches` and `$title` are parsed from the downloaded html but never used, which makes `$html` and the downloading itself rather useless).

Comment: i am just saving it on sql then i will use it to another page.

Comment: Well, you aren't currently. You're just saving the URL at the moment.

Comment: <?php
include("../db.php");


$url=$_GET["linki"];
$satauri=$_GET["satauri"];
$surati=$_GET["surati"];






if ($url==NULL){

$pdo -> exec("INSERT INTO `postss`(`title`, `image`) VALUES ('$satauri','$surati')");


}else {
  $html = file_get_contents("$url");
  preg_match('/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*?)" \/>/', $html, $matches);
  preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $html, $title);
  $pdo -> exec("INSERT INTO `postss`(`title`, `image`) VALUES ('$title[1]','$matches[1]')");
}

header("location:../allnews.php");





 ?>

Comment: $url=$_GET["linki"];
i am getting "linki" from form

Comment: and then parsing that link and save content to sql

Comment: 1) StackOverflow comments are not a chat. 2) I just showed you an example how to process a POST form. You use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. I'm not debugging your whole snippet.